# archive manager error message in 13.10

Tags: archive

I have several downloads in archive manager, but when I try to load them I get "error occurred when loading this archive".  Any suggestions or solutions?

Answer (score 1):

`Error occurred when loading this archive` means your archive file(tar.gz or tar.xz,etc) may be corrupted or partially downloaded.

Please try to redownload that archive file before decompressing it with archive manager.